# log4net is not logging to log file or console (external log4net.config file)

Tags: c#, logging, log4net, log4net-configuration

I created a a file called `log4net.config` in my project and added the following configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net" />
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="console" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
    </root>
    <appender name="console" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date %level %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <param name="File" value="${LOCALAPPDATA}\MyApp\LogFile.log" />
      <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5level [%d{yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss}] [%thread] (Line:%line) %M: - %m%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

After that, I added the line below to my `AssemblyInfo.cs` file:

`[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net.config", Watch = true)]`

In the application, I have the following static class:

```
public static class Logger
    {
        private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);


        public static void LogInfo(string msg)
        {
            log.Info(msg);
        }

        public static void LogDebug(string msg)
        {
            log.Debug(msg);
        }

        public static void LogWarn(string msg, Exception e)
        {
            log.Warn(msg, e);
        }

        public static void LogError(string msg, Exception e)
        {
            log.Error(msg, e);
        }
    }
```

Then I'm trying to log somewhere in the application in another class using `Logger.LogDebug("Error logger working.");`

However, I can't see any log file being created or written to it. What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:

I also added the following in my `app.config` file but I see nothing at all on my Output console...

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
</appSettings>
```

Comment: Eliminate the ACL Issues and change the ${LOCALAPPDATA}\... to C:\TEMP\LogFile.log and check if that works.

Comment: @lloyd still not working after the change.

Comment: probably removing log4net and adding in each configuration element at a time.

Comment: I tried your log4net.config file and it works fine. Are you sure the log4net.config file is copied to your destination folder? Also to enable log4net debugging, I would usually just change the log4net.config file, replacing `<log4net>` with `<log4net debug="true">`

Comment: @sgmoore I actually tried `<log4net debug="true">` but it doesn't show any strace from log4net. I don't think my log4net is even initialized...

Comment: [Docs](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html#attributes) say _".. it is worth noting that attributes are purely passive. They are information only. Therefore if you use configuration attributes you must invoke log4net to allow it to read the attributes. A simple call to LogManager.GetLogger will cause the attributes on the calling assembly to be read and processed. **Therefore it is imperative to make a logging call as early as possible during the application start-up, and certainly before any external assemblies have been loaded and invoked.**"_

Comment: Also, you can check `LogManager.GetRepository().Configured` to see if the configuration has been applied.

Comment: If this is running locally, you could try downloading and running Process Monitor from Microsoft/Sysinternals which will show you which files are being accessed. You should be able to see it if it is accessing or attempting to access your log4net.config file and whether it is trying to create the log file in %localappdata%\MyApp

Answer (score 1):

If you have the log4net configuration in a log4net logging configuration file, you do not have to add the configuration of the web.config (configuration tag and sections). Just add the log4net tags:

```
<log4net>
<root>
  <level value="ALL" />
  <appender-ref ref="console" />
  <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
</root>
<appender name="console" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date %level %logger - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
<appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <param name="File" value="${LOCALAPPDATA}\MyApp\LogFile.log" />
  <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Size" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
  <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
  <staticLogFileName value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5level [%d{yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss}] [%thread] (Line:%line) %M: - %m%n" />
  </layout>
</appender>
</log4net>
```

Comment: You don't **have to** add the configuration, but it doesn't seem to cause any problems if you do.

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce your mistake. Configure log4net in AssemblyInfo  works fine. maybe the problem in configuration. let me show you another implementation

```
    private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger("myLogger");
    private static string configFile = "log4net.config";
    static Logger()
    {
        XmlConfigurator.Configure(new FileInfo(configFile));
    }
```

log4net.config:

```
<log4net>
<logger name="myLogger">
  <level value="ALL" />
  <appender-ref ref="console" />
  <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
</logger>
<appender name="console" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date %level %logger - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
<appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <param name="File" value="${LOCALAPPDATA}\MyApp\LogFile.log" />
  <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Size" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
  <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
  <staticLogFileName value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5level [%d{yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss}] [%thread] (Line:%line) %M: - %m%n" />
  </layout>
</appender>
</log4net>
```

Comment: That is not the only way to configure log4net and should not be necessary for the OP as he is using log4net assembly attribute (see https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html#attributes).

Comment: @sgmoore thanks a lot for remark,i missed author message regarding configuration

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find out the issue thanks to stuartd's comment. My problem was, my full solution had 2 projects. I had only configured one project (which is not the start-up project) for log4net.

My original log4net configuration did not have any mistake. I simply added log4net reference to my start up project and added log4net configuration to that project as well and it started logging.

Many thanks to everyone who tested my config.